# How to add a complex constraint of 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tablel
(
    main_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    name_id CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    my_flag BIT,
    active BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (main_id)
)
```

I would like to add an extra constraint line on 'main flag' satisfying the following conditions:

- There can only be one record with `main_flag` set to true for each `name_id`.
- `main_flag` can only be set to true if active is also true

Can anybody help me?

Comment: *main flag* - you have *main_id* and *my_flag*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need to be served by 2 different objects, a filtered `UNIQUE INDEX` for the first, and a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` for the second.

For the first, you can create a filtered `UNIQUE INDEX` like this, which will mean that only `name_id` must be unique for rows where `my_flag` (I assume this is what you mean by "main_flag") is `1` (not "true", `bit` is not a boolean):

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_name_id_my_flag_equal_1 ON dbo.my_tablel (name_id)
WHERE my_flag = 1;
```

For the latter you can use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to check that the value of `my_flag` and `active` are both `1`, or `my_flag` is `0` or `NULL`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_tablel ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyFlag_Active
CHECK ((my_flag = 1 AND active = 1) OR my_flag = 0 OR my_flag IS NULL);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07ef6c3d68b0410f75c44da438b2a16b)